When in the anime were Phobos and Deimos first revealed to have humanoid forms?
In the animated canon of Sailor Moon, when (in which arc or episode) were Sailor Mars' companion animals - the crows Phobos and Deimos - first revealed to be able to transform into humanoid forms?
They appear in these forms in the Netflix OVA Sailor Cosmos. Were their forms revealed in any prior animated features?

they were revealed in Sailor Moon Eternal
